# Printing a list of folders which has been modified today

Tags: dired, directories, directory, find-dired

Is there any way to export a list of folder names which has been modified today using a dired mode or any other package on emacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a keyboard macro for that.

1. Switch to dired buffer
2. Make sure details (modification dates) are visible, `M-x dired-hide-details-mode` if necessary
3. Go to beginning of buffer (`M-<`)
4. Start keyboard macro (`C-x C-k C-s`)
5. Isearch for current day (I type `C-s Mar 16 RET`)
6. Mark current entry (`m`)
7. Go back to beginning of line (`C-a`)
8. End keyboard macro (`C-x C-k C-k`)
9. Repeat macro until bell rings (`C-u 0 C-x e`)
10. Now all modified entries are marked, type `C-u 0 w` to copy all of their names to the kill ring.

This will work for both files and directories. If you want to limit this only for directories, you can use [dired-filter](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks#dired-filter) package, available from MELPA. After you installed it, you can hit `/ d` in dired buffer (after step 2) to hide files in current buffer.

**EDIT:** If you use `dired-filter` package you can actually just use `dired-filter-by-predicate` command to keep only directories modified today, then mark everything (`U t`) and type `C-u 0 w`.